# intersect function returns different mode depending on input order

Tags: r

Probably the real question is "Should anyone care", but here's the inconsistency:

```
intersect(c(),1:3)
integer(0)
intersect(1:3,c())
NULL
```

The same thing happens with `setdiff`, but there it makes sense because `setdiff` is designed to be asymmetric with respect to its two inputs.
Now, it's more or less obvious from the source for `intersect` why this happens, as the algorithm is asymmetric even though the intersection of two sets is symmetric.

The question, I guess, is whether this could ever lead to code mangles when some parent function depends on the mode of the output.

(Background: I got some requests from a user to fix the current rev. of `package:vecsets` to properly handle empty set inputs, and I'd like to make the output match the class, mode, etc. of the base functions as closely as possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from `?intersect` , the documentation seems to imply vector of same "mode" is required. `c()` is "NULL". Using `as.integer()` to change the class of `c()` seems to work.

```
class(c())
# [1] "NULL"
class(1:3)
# [1] "integer"
class(as.integer(c()))
# [1] "integer"
intersect(c(1:3), as.integer(c()))
# integer(0)
intersect(as.integer(c()), c(1:3))
# integer(0)
```